# .crt and .key certificates from Vault CLI causes a TRUSTED CERTIFICATE error when running Docker container [NGINX]

Tags: docker, nginx, hashicorp-vault

I am working with Vault CLI and nginx right now and currently I need to grab home.crt and door.key from Vault CLI. After getting such data from the vault, I tried to copy it over to my dockerfile with the nginx.conf. I have verified that the nginx.conf works on its own but when I copy over the .crt and .key for SSL termination. I receive this error when trying to run the Dockerfile.

```
[emerg] 1#1: cannot load certificate "/etc/nginx/ssl/colossus.crt": PEM_read_bio_X509_AUX() failed (SSL: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE)
nginx: [emerg] cannot load certificate "/etc/nginx/ssl/colossus.crt": PEM_read_bio_X509_AUX() failed (SSL: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE)
```

I do not have direct access to openSSL, how can I combat this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The file `/etc/nginx/ssl/colossus.crt` is Vault's own CA certificate (in PEM format). It is not your nginx server certificate.

You can get Vault's CA with this command:

```
curl ${VAULT_ADDR}/v1/pki/ca/pem
```

If you have a multi-level CA, you can also get the whole chain. [Details here](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/api-docs/secret/pki#read-issuer-certificate).